# Mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy S6) keeps connecting and reconnecting when trying to connect with USB cable

Tags: windows-10, usb, connection, phone

I would like to ask for help with this problem which is extremely annoying. I have looked at several places but couldn't find any solution...

> The problem is simple:
>   I plug my phone (Samsung Galaxy S6 (G920F), custom ROM) into one of the USB ports on my PC. Soon, I hear the magic sound, receive a notification, device connected (I am using Windows 10). I try to do some operation on the phone, let's say copy files from the phone to the PC, but suddenly, totally out of the blue, the phone disconnects. Then it reconnects. Than it disconnects.
>   There is absolutely no pattern, it does this completely randomly.

I thought that it might be a hardware issue, something with the port, the pins, etc... So I've tried plugging it into all other ports, still no success.

On other forums, I found that you should disable some option in the Device Manager, done that (it's about whether Windows can put the device into sleep to preserve power), did nothing.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the battery charge level of this phone when it starts doing this?

Comment: It does this at any battery level.
That's why I said that it's completely random, regardless of battery level, time, port, etc.

Comment: Are there any kernel logs that you can collect and determine why Android wants to drop USB link?

Comment: @AliChen Where should I be looking for those?

Comment: You need to ask Android/Linux/Samsung people. This is their standard debug procedure, I have no idea. You need to enable proper log verbocity to include messages related to USB handling.

Comment: @AliChen But I can do that on Windows, right? Okay, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different cable? I had this issue with my iPhone SE and a third-party lightning cable. Using another one (I used the original from apple) did the trick.

Comment: No, I only have one cable, but it's the stock one.
Also, I noticed that when I plug the device into different PCs with this very cable, it works like a charm.
So the problem has to be with the PC. I just can't find out what it is.